# How to find the coordinates of nonzero elements of a 3-D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-deployment

I have a 3D matrix `A`, the size of which is `40*40*20` double. The values in 3D matrix is either `"0"` or `"1"`. The number of `"1"` in matrix A is 50. I know how to find the corresponding coordinates of the 3D matrix. The code looks like this:

```
[x y z] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A));
coords = [x y z];
```

My question is how to just find the coordinates `[xi yi zi] (i=1,2,...,50)` of the nonzero elements in 3D matrix `A`, and then assign values `a1, a2, a3, ..., a50` to the corresponding coordinates `[xi yi zi] (i=1,2,...,50)`, also assign `"NaN"` values to the other coordinates with zero values?

Comment: why deduct my points?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's because what you're asking isn't very clear.  Please try and give a numerical example of what you want... at least one a smaller dataset.

Comment: Looks like you have solved the problem already, with the proposd solution. You have x.y.z- indices. What more do you want? Further, you can do `A(A==0) = nan;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to change the nonzero/zero values of a matrix, using logical indexing [1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1),[2](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) you don't need `find` **or** `ind2sub`. [@patrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2903371/patrik) gave the technique in the comments for changing the zero values to NaN:

```
A(A==0) = nan;
```

You can do the same thing for the nonzero values:

```
A(A~=0) = a(1:sum(A~=0));
```

Note: You could replace `A~=0` above with any of the following:

```
~~A
A>0         %// IFF you have no negative values
find(A)     %// but the logical operations are faster
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. You already done half of this works. But , if you need some examples here is one:
use `ind2sub()` function to create array with nonzero elements coordinates. I show the 2D example, because it's easy to visualize results:

```
k = 0;
for i = 1:size(A,1)*size(A,2)
    if A(i) == 1
        [ I(k+1) J(k+1)] = ind2sub(s,i);
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

lets take a look at `I` and `J`:

```
A =

 1     0     0     0     1
 1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1
 1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
I = 1     2     4     5     3     4     5     2     3     5     3     4     5     1     3     4     5
J = 1     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3     4     4     4     5     5     5     5
```

so now you can do anything with it. for example, set your values. If we have array of values `a`:

```
for k = 1:size(I,2)
A(I(k),J(k)) = a(k);
end
```

Similarly, you can go this way to create the array of zero elements and to set them `Nan`. And it works for 3D the same way.

P.S. by the way, I don't understand why you don't want to use just loops like this:

```
for i: = 1:40
    for j = 1:40
        for k = 1:20
        if A(i,j,k) == 1
            A(i,j,k) = a(l);
            l = l + 1;
        else A(i,j,k) = NaN;
        l = l + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The reason why you generally stay away from loops is because it is slower. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/06/25/speeding-up-matlab-applications/ .  Loops are used depending on the situation.  In some situations, loops have comparable speed but in general they are slower.  In this case, you can definitely afford **not** to use loops.  As such, the use of `find` combined with `ind2sub` is probably going to be much faster with larger sized matrices than with your example that fortifies using loops.